# Spring Boot 3 - Convert from text[] column to List<String> attribute

Tags: postgresql, text, spring-boot-3, hibernate-6.x, hypersistence-utils

I am trying to convert database column of type `text[]` to Entity attribute of type `List<String>` in **Spring Boot 3.2.3**, **Hibernate 6.4.4**.

I tried setting it like this:

```
@Type(ListArrayType.class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
@Basic() // was used here in Spring Boot 2 as well
private List<String> myColumn = new ArrayList<>();
```

After that, I get the following error:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [my_column] in table [my_table]; found [_text (Types#ARRAY)], but expecting [text[] (Types#OTHER)]`

My **PostgreSQL** database column definition:
`my_column text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT '{someValue}'::text[],`

Used **hypersistence** library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions please, what am I doing wrong?